# Error on sign csr by ecdsa algorithm

Tags: openssl, pkcs#11

when I verify CSR by openssl this errors happened

> verify failure 2912:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:.\cry
>   pto\asn1\asn1_lib.c:150:
>
> 2912:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object
>   header:.\c rypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1306:
>
> 2912:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested
>   asn1 error:.\ crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:381:Type=ECDSA_SIG
>
> 2912:error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP
>   lib:.\crypto\asn 1\a_verify.c:221:
>
> Certificate Request:
>       Data:
>           Version: 3 (0x3)
>           Subject: C=IR, O=f, OU=f, CN=f
>           Subject Public Key Info:
>               Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
>                   Public-Key: (192 bit)
>                   pub:
>                       04:59:a4:e9:91:53:0d:32:95:cc:46:4b:93:b0:43:
>                       79:95:37:95:8b:07:3e:89:a9:04:f0:34:c0:07:49:
>                       aa:01:1b:fd:ef:df:7f:3c:f8:c0:34:4c:ed:ea:c6:
>                       44:10:66:ae
>                   ASN1 OID: prime192v1
>           Attributes:
>               a0:00
>       Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
>            d8:bb:cb:6b:85:94:22:f4:29:98:21:18:0e:8b:c5:c0:bd:17:
>            c8:24:ac:ac:00:bb:52:8b:a5:fc:c0:47:a7:de:65:b2:27:02:
>            80:e6:5d:b6:5d:66:e7:e2:5b:79:5c:f1
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- MIHEMIGDAgEDMDExCzAJBgNVBAYTAklSMQowCAYDVQQKEwFmMQowCAYDVQQLEwFm
>   MQowCAYDVQQDEwFmMEkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQEDMgAEWaTpkVMNMpXM
>   RkuTsEN5lTeViwc+iakE8DTAB0mqARv9799/PPjANEzt6sZEEGauoAAwCQYHKoZI
>   zj0EAQMxANi7y2uFlCL0KZghGA6LxcC9F8gkrKwAu1KLpfzAR6feZbInAoDmXbZd
>   ZufiW3lc8Q==
>   -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: It is symptoms of algorithm not supported or OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms.